# Submitting data in an array not displaying correct result

Tags: php, arrays

After reading several tutorials and similar pages in SO, I have written a few lines of code to capture data in an array. The result is sometimes showing correct inputs, but when one of the level is omitted, showing incorrect results.
The have written some JS code so that only when the Level checkbox is selected, the other 2 input boxes will be available (which I have not included here).
Can anyone of you please help me to identify what is wrong with this?

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
    height: 40px;
}
td {
    width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 text-align:center
}
input[type=number] {
 width:40%;
}
td input[type=number] {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>


<div class="checkbox">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>Level</td>
   <th>No. of Awards</td>
   <th>Prize</td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><lable>Level 3</lable><input type="checkbox" name="lev[]" id="box3" value="3"/></td>
   <td><input type="number" name="qty[]" id="box3a" value="1" min="0" /></td>
   <td>
    <select name="prz[]" id="box3b">
      <option value="Book Voucher">Book Voucher</option>
      <option value="Certificate">Certificate</option>
      <option value="Pennant">Pennant</option>
      <option value="Medal">Medal</option>     
    </select>  
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><lable>Level 4</lable><input type="checkbox" name="lev[]" id="box4" value="4"/></td>
   <td><input type="number" name="qty[]" id="box4a" value="1" min="0"/></td>  
   <td>
    <select name="prz[]" id="box4b">
      <option value="Book Voucher">Book Voucher</option>
      <option value="Certificate">Certificate</option>
      <option value="Pennant">Pennant</option>
      <option value="Medal">Medal</option> 
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><lable>Level 5</lable><input type="checkbox" name="lev[]" id="box5" value="5"/></td>
   <td><input type="number" name="qty[]" id="box5a" value="1" min="0"/></td>  
   <td>
    <select name="prz[]" id="box5b">
      <option value="Book Voucher">Book Voucher</option>
      <option value="Certificate">Certificate</option>
      <option value="Pennant">Pennant</option>
      <option value="Medal">Medal</option> 
    </select>  
   </td>
  </tr> 
 </table>

 <input id="save_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"> 
</form>

 

</div>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $level = $_POST['lev'];
 $qty = $_POST['qty'];
 $prz = $_POST['prz']; 


    for($i = 0; $i < count($level); $i++ )
    {
        echo "Level : "  .$level[$i];
        echo " Award Qty.: " .$qty[$i];
        echo  " Prize : " . $prz[$i];
        echo "<br/>";
    } 
}

?>
</body>
```

Comment: "but when one of the level is omitted, showing incorrect results." Share the "incorrect" output and the desired output.

Comment: If I select all the 3 checkboxes and fill up the rest of the input boxes, its showing correct result, but if I select, say, Level 5, I get: "Level : 5 Award Qty.: 1 Prize : Book Voucher", even though the Award qty is 6 or 7 and Prize is some other option.

Comment: Before the loop add: var_dump($_POST); share the output in the question.

Comment: Hi Ofir, I believe I know the cause of the issue. When a Level is left blank, then the next Level selected picks up the default Award Qty as 1 and the Prize as 'Book Voucher' from the previous empty Level. This is not happening when all the 3 checkboxes are selected. But unable to resolve the issue still.

Comment: Var_dump resullt:     array(4) { ["lev"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "5" } ["qty"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "5" } ["prz"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(11) "Certificate" [1]=> string(12) "Book Voucher" [2]=> string(5) "Medal" } ["submit"]=> string(4) "Save" }

Comment: I used a different approach to resolve the issue (although it may not be the ideal way). I have used a different name for the variables and then entered them on to arrays:  $lev = array($lev0, $lev1, $lev2);
 $qty = array($qty0, $qty1, $qty2);
 $prz = array($prz0, $prz1, $prz2);